# How to load collada model

Tags: three.js

I have used sketchup to convert a sketch file in a collada (dae) file.

```
loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader()
loader.load('collada_models/robot.dae', loaderSuccess)

loaderSuccess = function(collada){
   console.log(collada)
   model = collada.scene
   scene.add(model)
}
```

I get the model data in my console. But I dont see the model in my scene.
Any Ideas why? I have forgot something?

Lights, And AnimationFrame are added.

Edit:

```
collada.scene.children[ 0 ].geometry;
collada.scene.children[ 0 ].material;
```

are both undefined, is this a problem? A export problem?

Thanks!

Comment: where is your camera? it might be pointing in the wrong direction.

Comment: No, i have checked it with another object

Comment: You are right...its a positioning problem! but the axis of the imported element are very confusing...is there th posibility to fix them?

Comment: probably from the modeling package (ie. Sketchup).

Comment: whats a good way to do this? i want it to set 0,0,0 and the rotation axis should be in the middle

Comment: Sorry, don't know scketchup